# Javascript cross domain - "allow" other domains?

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

**Description of steps**

1. Write "callback" function on my custom page in my domain (called "MyCallbackCallback", for the sake of argument)
2. Open new window (from different domain) and pass function name in as part of query string
3. New window does what it needs to do then tries to access "MyCallback" from my custom page

This obviously **won't** work and will return "Access denied" error.

If there was a way of "allowing" the 3rd-party domain access to my domain that would solve the issue, of course. Is there such a thing? I know there is in Action Script, but JavaScript??

NB - I am aware that setting "document.domain" on both pages, (or creating both pages in the same domain) will solve the issue, but I almost certainly **won't** have this option.

If the answer is "you can't" that's fine - I just need to know. I have spent many hours searching and can't find a simple answer (there may not be one!)

Ta, Rob

Comment: Would JSONP be a solution here?

Comment: Getting cross domains to work is painfull... check this: http://easyxdm.net/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

Comment: @mgutt 4 years late mate. Literally what is the point?

Answer (score 4):

It’s not exactly clear from your question, but if you’re trying to use [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/), the server you’re requesting data from should add an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` HTTP header, like so:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.org/
```

Or, if it’s a public resource:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Older browsers don’t support CORS. If you need a fully cross-browser-compatible solution, use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP).

Comment: Hi Mathias - this looks exactly what I'm looking for. I've just added "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" to the header, but the 3rd party page still can't access my method. Here is the error: "Permission denied for <http://[the 3rd party domain]> to get property Window.ProcessDocument"  ....where "Window.ProcessDocument" is the method on my page...

Comment: The wildcard allows all origins, a specific string allows 1 origin, but is there a way to allow a specific list of origins? Not seeing that in the W3 specs anywhere.

Comment: @CraigLabenz You could have your server read out the `Origin` header that the client sends, see if it matches the list of allowed origins, and then send back the single `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: [origin]` header.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Cross-Domain AJAX requests:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_Access_Control
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd573303%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

[JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP) is the only method compatible with older browsers though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want cross-domain communication without serverside proxies (perfect for the kind of RPC that you are describing) then take a look at [easyXDM](http://easyxdm.net).

You can find multiple [demos here](http://consumer.easyxdm.net/current/example/).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, fixed now!