# PHP Async Function Call with AJAX

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I would like to retrieve some database data where the query is executed initially by an AJAX call.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$('form[incidentForm]').on('submit', requestResponders  );

var requestResponders = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    getResponders(latitude, longitude, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
}

function getResponders(latitude, longitude, callback) {

    var geoInformation = [];
    geoInformation.push({name:'latitude', value:latitude});
    geoInformation.push({name:'longitude', value:longitude});

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '../searchResponders',
        data: geoInformation,
        success: function(responders) {
            callback(responders);
        }
    })
};
```

**ROUTES**

```
Route::post('searchResponders','RespondersController@getAvailableResponders');
```

**PHP**

```
public function getAvailableResponders(Request $request) {
    $data = $request->all();
    $responder = ResponderManagement::searchResponders($data);
    return $responder;
}

public function searchResponders($geoInformation) {
    $lat = $geoInformation['latitude'];
    $lng = $geoInformation['longitude'];
    $results = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT STATEMENT));
    return $results;
}
```

When I use POSTMAN to check the functionality, everything works fine. I get the wished for response and a json is returned with the database entries searched for.

[image]

When I use the AJAX call, I receive an empty array.
[image]
[image]

Therefore I guess, that due to the async behaviour, the return value is already returned, before the query in the DB has finished.

But I don't see why. I the ajax call, only on success I call the callback method to show the data. So I would guess the database query should have finished by that time already.

Can someone support me here please?

**UPDATE 1:**
I updated my function now

```
public function searchResponders($geoInformation) {
    $lat = $geoInformation['latitude'];
    $lng = $geoInformation['longitude'];
    $results = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT STATEMENT));
    echo json_encode($results);
}
```

But the returned value when logged in the console is still empty. whereas in the POSTMAN POST call everything is returned

**Update 2**
I grabbed a screenshot showing the content of the AJAX call in a chrome debugger. But this seems fine to me? Can someone help me out here? The response is still empty, but the direct call works fine.

[image]

**UPDATE 3**
I tested, if the success block is being called, which is the case. but when I log the content of the response data in the ajax request itself, it is already empty. So when the ajax request is being made to the URL with POST and the data to be sent, it returns empty. But isn't this the same approach as make the POST request by POSTMAN for example? There a response is being made.

Comment: You have to `echo` results to AJAX.

Comment: What happens when you return $data from `getAvailableResponders()` ?

Comment: Then I get the input data needed to perform the query.

Comment: Most likely related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351236/javascript-cross-domain-allow-other-domains

Answer (score 1):

`return` does not send results to AJAX, you have to `echo` the output.
Wrap the output in `json_encode()` is it is an array, or any other complex structure other then a string or number. I don't think it hurts to just always use `json_encode`.

Comment: Depends on the framework that he's using, which we don't really know anything about. I am guessing it's Laravel from the `Routing::post` call, but it's not definitive. Also he has already stated that it works if you call it directly, but not when it is called via an AJAX call.

Comment: Sorry.. Yes.. I am using Laravel

Comment: I tried that approach but no feedback at all. See the screenshots added

Comment: Could it be that the callback is already executed before the database has been queried?

Comment: Its possible, I'm no JS expert, but if you put `console.log(responders);` as the first line in your success function, you will know if the server is giving you any data.

Comment: I don't have a clue whats going on here... I see the output cleary in the API call

Comment: Interesting.. I just did this.. and the result is empty

Comment: Might be helpful to add and error function to the ajax call `error: function(e){ console.log(e); }`